# VBA for creating new sheets based on dynamic range in Index sheet

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, excel-formula

I am looking for experts' creation. I ran out of idea and dont think formula will do the trick I am after. In a workbook "schedule", there is the sheet "extractedData" extract information from another workbook. 2nd sheet "INDEX" will list required information from "extractedData". on "INDEX" sheet, date / DocNum / LotNum / ManDate / Qty will list from column A to E respectively. I am after some VBA magic that will create new sheets based on "INDEX" sheet and name each sheets based on DocNum range. The number of data in row will increase as more data coming in. Thanks the help.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you're looking for ?

```
Sub TEST()
    For i = 1 to 10 'For example
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = Worksheets("INDEX").Range("A" & i).Text
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Macronaute, the data range will grow

Comment: @PaulChao, is it ok for you with the Edit ?

Comment: it work! can the number of rows update dynamically ?

Comment: Yes, you need to add an integer variable like : `For i = 10 to iNb_Line`. Do not hesitate to accept the answer if it's ok for you, I would be grateful @PaulChao !